# Generate Logical model from oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I know i can generate a sql script from a logical model in data modeler, can i do the opposite?
i created the database from django and migrate to oracle, o generate an logical model would be really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In Data Modeler, File - Import

Choose either your SQL file(s) or use a database connection to import a data dictionary from the database.

This will give you a relational model.

Then you can use the engineer to logical model button to get your logical design and ERD.

Comment: Excellent news @nuevakenia!